# Paragraph breakage, one page to the other page, in detail section of Crystal Reports

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, crystal-reports

I have made a report in Crystal Reports, it has a detail section, i have dragged a variable carrying text and if the paragraph of the text longer, i want its half of the part should be gone to the next page, as we see in text books and as it is a standward way on A4 paper.
When i write a variable carrying data in text for detail, this problem occurs.  I had used some algorithm or like that to divide the data into two parts and made two variables, but as data can be html also so that algorithm does not work in very good manner. I just want to use crystal reports functionality. Thanks in advance.I am attaching an image for further understanding.[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The history field should have a property called 'keep together'. I'm guessing its set to true and should be changed to false to allow the field to be split across a page break.